# how to set up correctly httpd/apache on vagrant box?

Tags: apache, networking, vagrant

I'm having some misunderstanding on how to set up a running vagrant box (choosed centos)  with httpd service.

I have already my vagrant box up, I set up correctly httpd .

```
 [vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo  /etc/init.d/httpd status
 httpd (pid  2657) running...
```

On Vagrantfile I added the line (then a vagrant up/vagrant provision to reaload it):

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.2"
```

Then if I ssh into my vagrant and run a ifconfig I get:

```
 [vagrant@localhost ~]$ ifconfig
  eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A2:03:A5
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea2:3a5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:18590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:15457857 (14.7 MiB)  TX bytes:553193 (540.2 KiB)

   lo Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

It looks like the ip I wanted to associate to my vagrant machine was not considered. I expected "192.168.0.2" to appear after ifconfig

Should I perform some manual configuration?

Other consequences:
if I open my browser (from host machine) and digit http://10.0.2.15 I get back : ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE ?
I cannot ping successfully 192.168.0.2 from host.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, as you see, `httpd` service is running.

```
192.168.0.2  localhost
```

Add above entry into `/etc/hosts` in your host.